Resetting id in h2 database Spring Boot Test
I am testing my application using the H2 database, and I need to clear the tables and reset the ID fields after each test method. I tried to do this using TRUNCATE TABLE book, reader RESTART IDENTITY, but I am encountering an error. Could you please advise on the best way to do this? I don't want to recreate the schema before each test method, as that is a potential solution but is resource-intensive. And I prefer not to use DirtiesContext.
Annotations I'm using to configure Test Class:
package com.example.booklibrary.controllers.integration.annotation;

import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlGroup;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:db/schema.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_CLASS)
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:db/reset-data.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public @interface ControllerIT {}

Here's my schema.sql:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reader;

CREATE TABLE reader
(
    id   BIGSERIAL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT readers_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE book
(
    id        BIGSERIAL,
    name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    author    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    reader_id BIGINT,
    CONSTRAINT book_PK PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT book_readers_FK FOREIGN KEY (reader_id) REFERENCES reader (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

Here's my reset-data.sql:
TRUNCATE TABLE book,reader RESTART IDENTITY;

The error I'm receiving while trying to execute TRUNCATE query:
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [db/reset-data.sql]: TRUNCATE TABLE book,reader RESTART IDENTITY
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.execute(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$9(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:361)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.lambda$executeWithoutResult$0(TransactionOperations.java:68)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:361)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$4(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:274)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:274)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:221)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:164)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:320)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:240)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

I tried to do this using TRUNCATE TABLE book, reader RESTART IDENTITY, but I am encountering an error.

wouldn't it be simple to just keep this line @Sql(scripts = "classpath:db/schema.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_CLASS) and change it to execute before each test method? since it anyways drops and recreates the tables.

regarding your problem i think the error is in sql TRUNCATE TABLE book,reader RESTART IDENTITY; - you can't chain multiple sql statements with , you have to separate truncate with ; e.g. TRUNCATE TABLE book. I don' think you can/need to RESTART anything, recreating the table with "restart" the ids
